# Writing a query that lists a count grouped by another table

Tags: sql

Hi guys I am trying to  Write a query that returns a count of all the tbl_Object grouped by their Constellation.

Here is the image of my model
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnIDZ.gif

Can I write a simple SELECT * FROM, or will I have to join the tables together, and I am unsure of how to get a count. This is the code I have thought of so far, though I know it is far off.

```
SELECT COUNT(PK_object)
FROM tbl_object
GROUP BY tb_constellation.strName;
```

Comment: Which DB are you using? MySQL? SQLite?

Comment: The code doesn't even run.  You thought wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT Constellation_FK, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_object
GROUP BY Constellation_FK;
```

Comment: OP asks to group by the name. This only groups the table by the ID (although it is grouped correctly)

Comment: edited answer and added the constellation_FK in the result

Comment: Constellation_FK is only the foreign key to a table. You should do a join to that table and SELECT the name

Comment: it is difficult to give more specific answer without even knowing the DB being used.

Comment: Then you should ask OP ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far guys, I am using Microsoft SQL Server, db_constellation. didn't realize it made a difference, I'm relatively new to coding.

Comment: @Jorgio I don't see SQL Server tag on your question.  Is it too hard to put it????  It helps people help you.  It's useless if people give you solution to the wrong dbms.